# Triangle inequality on nearest integer function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Consider the distance to the nearest integer function, $\|\cdot\|$. Why is there an analogue of the triangle inequality in this case:
$$\|a+b\| \geq \|a\| - \|b\|?$$

Moreover, assume $\|b\| < 1/2$, is it true that
$$\|a+b\| \geq \|a\| - \|b\| \geq \|a\|/2?$$
I have this feeling reading a proof, however I do not see any reason for this to hold.

Comment: your assumption is ||b|| < 1/2, but yours conclusion is based on b< ||a||/2

Comment: @runway44 Oh yeah, I read the question wrong. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

Proof of the first inequality:
Without loss of generality, suppose that $a, b \in [-\tfrac 12, \tfrac 12]$.
If $a$ and $b$ have different sign, we find $\|a+b\| = |a+b| \geq | (|a|-|b|) | \geq |a|-|b| = \|a\| - \|b\|$ by the reverse triangle inequality. Otherwise suppose (again wlog) that $a$ and $b$ are both positive. If $a+b \leq \frac 12$, the same argument as before applies as again $\|a+b\| = |a+b|.$ Otherwise, we find
$$\|a+b\| = 1-a-b \geq \|a\|-\|b\|$$
as $1-a > a = \|a\|$ and $b = \|b\|$.

The second inequality is wrong: Consider $a = b = \tfrac 14$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification! As for the second question, I tried to simplify the situation but it is more precisely as follows: $\|na/d\| - \|bn\|$ where $n<d$ and $|ndb| < 1/2$. Is this sufficient to conclude?